# What is a secret on Devil's Playground?

Tags: starcraft-2

Team Liquid lists the following secrets for [The Devil's Playground](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/The_Devil%27s_Playground) campaign mission:

> ### Easter Eggs
>
> #### Diablo
>
> Can be found on an Island towards the southeast corner of the map.

I've found it, but can do nothing with him. What is a purpose of this secret? What can I do with those Diablo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that it exists at all is the secret. It's just a neat little reference to Diablo inside StarCraft, that's all.  It doesn't do anything special other than look cool.

Comment: What's the secret?! >w<

Answer (score 0):

There is a mini Diablo in the bottom right (south-east) corner which is there just for decoration.

[Here is a copy of a video which shows it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QL-c01znwYc)  There really is nothing to do with it, its just there as a reference in between the different franchises in which Blizzard is known for doing.